# Partial derivatives using polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, partial-derivative

I was given the following problems as practice, and I've sold all but one. However, I am not sure that my answers are correct.

> Calculate $(\partial r/\partial x)_y$ , $(\partial r/\partial y)_x$ , $(\partial θ/\partial x)_y$ ,$(\partial y/\partial x)_r$, $(\partial r/\partial \theta)_x$
>
> $x=r\cos(\theta)$, $y=r\sin(\theta)$

I have that

> $(\partial r/\partial x)_y=\cos(\theta)$
>
> $(\partial r/\partial y)_x=\sin(\theta)$
>
> $(\partial y/\partial x)_r=-\cot(\theta)$
>
> $(\partial \theta/\partial x)y=-\sin(\theta)/r$

Would $(\partial r/\partial \theta)_x$ then be equal to $r\tan\theta$?

Comment: Please use math formatting to remove ambiguities.. Are you asking about $$ \left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right) y = \frac{y}{ \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} }= \frac{r \sin \theta}{ \frac{\partial }{\partial r}( r \cos \theta) } = r \tan \theta$$ for example?

Comment: I think he meant the number right ahead the brakets to mean that this is made constant.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Why do you say that?  All of the answers are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.  Holding $y$ fixed we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}&=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\\\
&=\frac xr\\\\
&=\cos(\theta)
\end{align}$$

---

Similarly, holding $x$ fixed we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}&=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\\\
&=\frac yr\\\\
&=\sin(\theta)
\end{align}$$

---

Then, holding $r$ fixed we see that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is constant.  Hence,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}&=0\\\\
&=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}
\end{align}$$

whereupon solving for $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ we find that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}&=-\frac xy\\\\
&=-\cot(\theta)
\end{align}$$

---

Finally, holding $y$ fixed, we have $x=y\cot(\theta)$ so that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}&=1\\\\
&=y\left(-\csc^2(\theta)\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\right)
\end{align}$$

whereupon solving for $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}$ we find that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}&=-\sin^2(\theta)/y\\\\
&=-\sin^2(\theta)/(r\sin(\theta))\\\\
&=-\sin(\theta)/r
\end{align}$$